# R: ggplot2: Unable to plot points from a data.frame

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

So I want to do a simple plot where the following x-coordinates should be plotted as points. This is what my data.frame looks like:

```
   gap_pos
1 50646312
2 50647076
3 50647511
4 50647512
5 50647513
6 50647546
```

Now I have tried to do it as simple as possible:

```
gap_plot <- ggplot() + geom_point(data=gaps, aes(x=gap_pos))
```

Then the following error occurred:

```
Error in exists(name, envir = env, mode = mode) : 
argument "env" is missing, with no default
```

What can I do about this? I am totally stuck.

Edit:

The following two lines do not return an error but still do not plot anything.

```
gap_plot <- ggplot() + geom_point(data=gaps, aes(x=gap_pos , y = gap_pos))
gap_plot <- ggplot() + geom_point(data=gaps, aes(x=gap_pos , y = 1))
```

Comment: for geom_point() you should supply both `x` and `y` coordinates

Comment: If I add  `y=1` it returns no error but it also does not plot anything.

Comment: if you want to plot only these points you can assign `y` to be the same value of `x` so it will be something like this `gap_plot <- ggplot() + geom_point(data=gaps, aes(x=gap_pos , y = gap_pos))` but I'm not sure if you want this result

Comment: It's the same result like adding y =1 it returns no error anymore but it does not plot anything :/

Comment: No , It should work fine I think you're not executing the plot try to run `gap_plot ` , check this code `gap_plot <- ggplot() + geom_point(data=gaps, aes(x=gap_pos , y = gap_pos))
gap_plot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
gaps = data.frame(gap.pos = c(50646312, 50647076, 50647511, 50647512, 50647513, 50647546))
gap_plot <- ggplot(gaps) + geom_point(aes(x=gap.pos, y=1))
```

you have to call the plot you produced to actually see the plot

```
gap_plot
```

Comment: A simple `y=1` will work - the `1` gets repeated. Normal R recycling rules *dont* apply though, it has to be length 1 or the same length as the data.

Comment: @Spacedman true and I edited. Interestingly the OP came up with that very solution themselves but reported it doesn't produce a plot. I guess the problem is that the plot was only produced but not called afterwards as pointed out in the comments above.

Comment: The problem was that my graphics device got a bug. After I called dev.close() your solutions worked fine

Answer (score 1):

You have to give a `y` aesthetic for points. I'd add a factor with a single level to make a nice `y` axis:

```
> gap=data.frame(gap_pos=c(50646312, 50647076, 50647511, 50647512, 50647513, 50647513, 50647546))
> gap$data=factor("Data")
> ggplot() + geom_point(data=gap, aes(x=gap_pos, y=data))+ylab("")
```

Which gives:
[image: single Y plot]