# ggplot2: using geom_point() and not all of my character labels are plotting on the X-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, bioinformatics, geom-point

I am trying to graph using the `ggplot2` `geom_point` call in `R`. However, when I plot the desired graph, my X-labels that are words (not numbers) do not all show up on the X-axis.

To begin, here is some reproducible data:

```
Bac <- data.frame(logFC = seq(-1, 3.5, 0.19), 
             ASV_Fam = c("ASV_31; Bdellovibrionaceae", "ASV_152; Reyranellaceae", "ASV_102; Hymenobacteraceae", "ASV_124; Nitrospiraceae", "ASV_141; NA", 
                                                          "ASV_180; Microscillaceae", "ASV_259; Microscillaceae", "ASV_272; Chitinophagaceae", "ASV_79; Chthoniobacteraceae", 
                                                          "ASV_266; Chthoniobacteraceae", "ASV_106; Nitrosomonadaceae", "ASV_121; Nitrospiraceae", "ASV_184; Methylophilaceae", "ASV_115; Chthoniobacteraceae",
                                                          "ASV_123; Nitrosomonadaceae", "ASV_143; Haliangiaceae", "ASV_139; NA", "ASV_159; Micrococcaceae", "ASV_185; Xanthobacteraceae", "ASV_227; Chitinophagaceae",   
                                                          "ASV_233; NA", "ASV_239; Chitinophagaceae", "ASV_255; NA", "ASV_204; Longimicrobiaceae"), 
             Phylum = c("Bdellovibrionota", "Proteobacteria", "Bacteroidota", "Nitrospirota",     
                        "Proteobacteria", "Bacteroidota", "Bacteroidota", "Bacteroidota",     
                        "Verrucomicrobiota", "Verrucomicrobiota", "Proteobacteria", "Nitrospirota",     
                        "Proteobacteria", "Verrucomicrobiota", "Proteobacteria", "Myxococcota",      
                        "Proteobacteria", "Actinobacteriota", "Proteobacteria", "Bacteroidota",     
                        "Proteobacteria", "Bacteroidota", "Cyanobacteria","Gemmatimonadota"))

Bac$Family <- gsub("^[^.]*;", "", Bac$ASV_Fam)
```

The closest I have found to my error is this post: [Unable to plot points from a data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730229/r-ggplot2-unable-to-plot-points-from-a-data-frame). Following instructions from there, I added a factor with a single level by following the suggested code:

```
Bac$logFC <- factor(Bac$logFC, levels = unique(Bac$logFC))
Bac$ASV_Fam <- factor(Bac$ASV_Fam, levels = unique(Bac$ASV_Fam))
```

Graphing:

```
ggplot(Bac, aes(x = Family, y = logFC, color = Phylum)) + geom_point() +
scale_x_discrete(labels = toShow$ASV_Fam) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", size = 9, angle = -90))
```

However, this still does not plot all of my X-labels that I need to see. Here is the graph I get:

[image]

As you can see, it only plotted 14 of my 24 labels I have passed for the X-axis. All of my points are there, but some vertical lines show more than 1 point and only 1 label is associated with that vertical line. See for example X-axis labels: `ASV_152; Reyranellaceae`, `ASV_102; Hymenobacteraceae`, `ASV_266; Chthoniobacteraceae`, etc.

I am not sure why these are not given separate X-axis labels and are instead being graphed on the same vertical line, thus reducing the total labels plotted on the X-axis.

Other work arounds I have tried: widening the pdf via the `pdf()` command, widening the graph by passing `coord_fixed(ratio = 0.25)`, but none of these options work.

In addition, passing the following code `scale_y_discrete(breaks = seq(-1, 4, 0.5))` so that I can not have so many numbers show up in the Y-axis does not work. I think it's because the y-axis has been set as a factor, so I tried to keep it numeric, but that isn't working either.

Any clue into what is going on would be very helpful!

For reference, here is the ouput of my session `sessionInfo()`

```
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check `dim(table(Bac$Family))`, there exists `14` unique values in `Family`, and as you set x axis of your plot by `x = Family`, there only 14 values exists.

I'm not sure about your purpose, but if you want all 24 labels(`ASV_Fam`) in x axis and one point per each, instead of `x = Family`, try `x = ASV_Fam`

Please let me know if this plot is not what you wanted.

```
ggplot(Bac, aes(x = ASV_Fam, y = logFC, color = Phylum)) + geom_point() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", size = 9, angle = -90))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! This absolutely worked. Something so simple. Thank-you. However, the `scale_y_discrete(breaks = seq(-1, 4, 0.5))` added to the graph is still is not working. Any clues as to what is going on there?

Comment: I just answered my own question. I switched out `scale_y_discrete(breaks = seq(-1, 4, 0.5))` to `scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-1, 4, 0.5))` and the scaling works as intended. Thanks for your help!